# Angular 6 - Dynamically set [required] on mat-select

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my Angular v6 app, I am trying to display a drop-down and set it as `required` based on a boolean value, where it is set on a checkbox's value.  Here is a snippet of that code in my template (`includeModelVersion` is initially set to `false`):

```html
<mat-checkbox class='matCheckbox' (change)="includeModelVersion = !includeModelVersion">Run Model</mat-checkbox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<mat-form-field *ngIf="includeModelVersion">
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Model Version" formControlName="modelVersionCtrl" [required]="includeModelVersion">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let model of modelData" [value]="model?.MODEL_VERSION">{{model.MODEL_VERSION}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In my .ts constructor I am defining my boolean value:

```ts
includeModelVersion: boolean = false;
```

The drop down is displaying properly, using the *ngIf, but the issue is related to `[required]="includeModelVersion"` within `mat-select`.

If I do not check the checkbox then the form is able to submit fine, but if I check the checkbox and then uncheck it, the drop-down remains required, even though `includeModelVersion=false`.

Am I missing something here, or am I defining something incorrectly?

Comment: Can you share stackblitz demo?

Comment: Here is a stackblitz demo that appears to work when I remove the *ngIf: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-86dmw6 ... when I include *ngIf I am getting an error that I do not see in my own development environment.  Unfortunately I would like to hide/show the drop down based on the checkbox selection, and this functionality is currently working for me in my local dev env.  Maybe I should show/hide a div instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using reactive forms, you can dynamically add 'required' validator to the the formControl.

```
this.form.controls["modelVersionCtrl"].setValidators(Validators.required);
```

You can execute this statement based on certain conditions in the component class.

Comment: This will work when the checkbox is initially checked, but how do I remove a Validator when the checkbox is unchecked?  I'm having trouble figuring that out.

Comment: Bind to the checkbox 'changed' event, if the checkbox is checked then use the above code to add required validator. If the checkbox is not checked then use `this.form.controls["modelVersionCtrl"].clearValidators()` and then don't forget to call `this.form.controls["modelVersionCtrl"].updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: Thank you, this solved it!  I added `(change)="modelCheckboxChange($event)"` and then in my .ts file I added a new function `modelCheckboxChange(event) {
    if (event.checked) {
      this.firstFormGroup.controls["modelVersionCtrl"].setValidators(Validators.required);
    } else {
      this.firstFormGroup.controls["modelVersionCtrl"].clearValidators();
      this.firstFormGroup.controls["modelVersionCtrl"].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
    this.includeModelVersion = !this.includeModelVersion;
  }`

Comment: but this does not give you the `required` mat-select property, which is the thing that renders the mandatory-field-indicating asterisk

Comment: yeah it won't update that flag. that flag is shown using 'required' html attribute on the input. the above required tag will just change the state of the Angular Form object. To show the asterisks, get refereence to the input elemnt and set the required attribute on it in dom.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

You are using reactive forms, I think you can define `Validators.required` when defining the form control inside a form group like this:

```
this.fb.group({
  'modelVersionCtrl': ['', Validators.required]
})
```

If you want to compose your required based on some condition, try `Validators.compose([<your conditional logic here>])`.

The beauty of Angular Reactive Forms is having validations set programmatically rather than in the template. Hope that helped!

Comment: Yes, Please share an example